# Unable to Read byte Stream in C#

Tags: c#, .net, networking, tcp, client-server

I am building a client server application where a client has to send some byte stream and the server responds to it based on the bytes received from the Client. I am using the `NetworkStream.Write` and `NetworkStream.Read` methods to send and receive data. The client is able to create a TCP connection to the server. After accepting the connection, the server does `NetworkStream.Read` and waits for some input from the client. The Client sends the data using the `NetworkStream.Write` and also does `NetworkStream.Flush`. But the Server never wakes up from the Read.

Can you guys suggest me what could be the problem here or if you know any other methods to send Byte Stream over a TCP Connection in C# please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: First: please post the actual code your using - Second: try to close the connection on the client after your write your bytes, because my guess is, that you are using the *stream* not quite the right way

Comment: I can see from the code provided that it's most likely to be interference from particles emitted by Neptune. I highly recommend that you shield your entire city in tin foil for higher quality transmissions.

Comment: First: I already explained the code.. There is only 2 lines which I am concerned about in this question, Network.Write from my client and Network.Read on my Server.

Second, I am creating a connection and doing Write from my client  and after that I do a Read to get the response from the server. I am deadlocked there.

Comment: Are you sure your .Read really "waits for some input from the client" and doesn't just return that 0 bytes were read?

Answer (score 1):

Smart-ass comments aside: even though you are only interested in 2 lines of code, I'm willing to bet your problem is someplace else in your code.

Using a modified version of the code found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), I constructed a simple example that works in my testing.

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        TcpListener server = null;
        try
        {
            // Set the TcpListener on port 13000.
            Int32 port = 13000;
            IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");

            // TcpListener server = new TcpListener(port);
            server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);

            // Start listening for client requests.
            server.Start();

            // Buffer for reading data
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];

            Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... ");

            // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
            // You could also user server.AcceptSocket() here.
            TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("Connected!");

            // Get a stream object for reading and writing
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

            stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes));
            // Shutdown and end connection
            client.Close();
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Stop listening for new clients.
            server.Stop();
        }


        Console.WriteLine("\nHit enter to continue...");
        Console.Read();
    }
```

The read call will wait and return when I send it 1 byte with another program.  We would need to see some code to figure out why this works and yours does not.